# Why do some SMS messages get overwritten in Messages?

Tags: iphone, messages, sms

I have at least 2 SMS conversations where every new message replaces the previous one. One thread is a notification from Vodafone that tells me I had a missed call who didn't leave a message. But when I open the conversation thread, there's only 1 single message there, and each time I get a missed call, the time changes. So instead of having a history of multiple messages, I see only the most recent one. Same for another SMS thread from my bank sending 2FA codes. These are on 2 separate SIM cards.

What's going on? Why is Messages deleting or overwriting SMS messages instead of adding them to the list?